# battlefield 3 crash cause

Tags: logging, crash

hope someone can help to figure out what its causing battlefield 3 to crash, every time i try to start the game almost immediately the game crash, here there is the crash log, im not that good to understand the crash log, so I was hoping some of you could help me.

```html
Version=1
EventType=APPCRASH
EventTime=131346878558342701
ReportType=2
Consent=1
UploadTime=131346878558572727
ReportIdentifier=8475bc90-0f3d-11e7-82b6-10bf4876201c
IntegratorReportIdentifier=8475bc8f-0f3d-11e7-82b6-10bf4876201c
WOW64=1
NsAppName=bf3.exe
Response.BucketId=8b2e4f6a53aa18f4384f86a1e0e84c65
Response.BucketTable=1
Response.LegacyBucketId=73989182840
Response.type=4
Sig[0].Name=Nome applicazione
Sig[0].Value=bf3.exe
Sig[1].Name=Versione applicazione
Sig[1].Value=1.6.0.0
Sig[2].Name=Timestamp applicazione
Sig[2].Value=511c9356
Sig[3].Name=Nome modulo con errori
Sig[3].Value=StackHash_5861
Sig[4].Name=Versione modulo con errori
Sig[4].Value=0.0.0.0
Sig[5].Name=Timestamp modulo con errori
Sig[5].Value=00000000
Sig[6].Name=Codice eccezione
Sig[6].Value=c0000005
Sig[7].Name=Offset eccezione
Sig[7].Value=PCH_3B_FROM_ntdll+0x0003C7EC
DynamicSig[1].Name=Versione SO
DynamicSig[1].Value=6.3.9600.2.0.0.256.48
DynamicSig[2].Name=ID impostazioni locali
DynamicSig[2].Value=1040
DynamicSig[22].Name=Informazioni aggiuntive 1
DynamicSig[22].Value=5861
DynamicSig[23].Name=Ulteriori informazioni 2
DynamicSig[23].Value=5861822e1919d7c014bbb064c64908b2
DynamicSig[24].Name=Ulteriori informazioni 3
DynamicSig[24].Value=6ee2
DynamicSig[25].Name=Ulteriori informazioni 4
DynamicSig[25].Value=6ee2432e64e99bdcea5e4be767a3b1a2
UI[2]=C:\Program Files (x86)\Origin Games\Battlefield 3\bf3.exe
LoadedModule[0]=C:\Program Files (x86)\Origin Games\Battlefield 3\bf3.exe
LoadedModule[1]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
LoadedModule[2]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNEL32.DLL
LoadedModule[3]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll
LoadedModule[4]=C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
LoadedModule[5]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SHLWAPI.dll
LoadedModule[6]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\USER32.dll
LoadedModule[7]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\msvcrt.dll
LoadedModule[8]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\combase.dll
LoadedModule[9]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\GDI32.dll
LoadedModule[10]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\RPCRT4.dll
LoadedModule[11]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SspiCli.dll
LoadedModule[12]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.dll
LoadedModule[13]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
LoadedModule[14]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
LoadedModule[15]=C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
LoadedModule[16]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSCTF.dll
LoadedModule[17]=C:\PROGRA~2\ORIGIN~1\BATTLE~1\Core\awc.dll
LoadedModule[18]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ADVAPI32.dll
LoadedModule[19]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SHELL32.dll
LoadedModule[20]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ole32.dll
LoadedModule[21]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\OLEAUT32.dll
LoadedModule[22]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SHCORE.dll
LoadedModule[23]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\profapi.dll
LoadedModule[24]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\kernel.appcore.dll
LoadedModule[25]=C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
LoadedModule[26]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\clbcatq.dll
LoadedModule[27]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTSP.dll
LoadedModule[28]=C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
LoadedModule[29]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\bcrypt.dll
LoadedModule[30]=C:\PROGRA~2\ORIGIN~1\BATTLE~1\Core\EACore.dll
LoadedModule[31]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WS2_32.dll
LoadedModule[32]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
LoadedModule[33]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINHTTP.dll
LoadedModule[34]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WININET.dll
LoadedModule[35]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WTSAPI32.dll
LoadedModule[36]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\PSAPI.DLL
LoadedModule[37]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\COMDLG32.dll
LoadedModule[38]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\NSI.dll
LoadedModule[39]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\iertutil.dll
LoadedModule[40]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll
LoadedModule[41]=C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.9600.17810_none_7c5b6194aa0716f1\COMCTL32.dll
LoadedModule[42]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
LoadedModule[43]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll
LoadedModule[44]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\cfgmgr32.dll
LoadedModule[45]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DEVOBJ.dll
LoadedModule[46]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\urlmon.dll
LoadedModule[47]=C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.8387_none_5094ca96bcb6b2bb\MSVCP90.dll
LoadedModule[48]=C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.8387_none_5094ca96bcb6b2bb\MSVCR90.dll
LoadedModule[49]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dxgi.dll
LoadedModule[50]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dwmapi.dll
LoadedModule[51]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DINPUT8.dll
LoadedModule[52]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll
LoadedModule[53]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
LoadedModule[54]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINNSI.DLL
LoadedModule[55]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DSOUND.dll
LoadedModule[56]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\POWRPROF.dll
LoadedModule[57]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\d3d11.dll
LoadedModule[58]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\XINPUT9_1_0.dll
LoadedModule[59]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\D3DCOMPILER_43.dll
LoadedModule[60]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\d3dx11_43.dll
LoadedModule[61]=C:\Program Files (x86)\Origin Games\Battlefield 3\Engine.BuildInfo_Win32_retail_dll.dll
LoadedModule[62]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\nvapi.dll
LoadedModule[63]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SETUPAPI.dll
LoadedModule[64]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINSTA.dll
LoadedModule[65]=C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\3D Vision\nvStereoApiI.dll
LoadedModule[66]=C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\3D Vision\nvSCPAPI.dll
LoadedModule[67]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINTRUST.dll
LoadedModule[68]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPT32.dll
LoadedModule[69]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSASN1.dll
LoadedModule[70]=C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
LoadedModule[71]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DNSAPI.dll
LoadedModule[72]=C:\Windows\System32\rasadhlp.dll
LoadedModule[73]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\nvwgf2um.dll
LoadedModule[74]=C:\Windows\system32\nvspcap.dll
LoadedModule[75]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\HID.DLL
State[0].Key=Transport.DoneStage1
State[0].Value=1
FriendlyEventName=Ha smesso di funzionare
ConsentKey=APPCRASH
AppName=Battlefield 3™
AppPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Origin Games\Battlefield 3\bf3.exe
NsPartner=windows
NsGroup=windows8
ApplicationIdentity=9C09DF51F0407580B0CF441AFB93C80F
```

Comment: I think even if it has word "crash" and "logs", doesn't mean a lot of us here can help you. Because this site contains lot of programmers, but not a lot of game modders. [Try this site](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/), maybe you got a better luck

Comment: thanks a lot koceeng!